# ASP MVC 5 Integration Testing vs Unit Testing with SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, sdk, asp.net-mvc-5

I’ve seen lots of info on this topic but wanted to provide a specific example and ask some specific questions.

I’m currently in the middle of a development project in which I’m programming against a telephony system via the OEM provided SDK.  I’ve created several interfaces & classes that extend the functionality of the SDK and have refactored these to support dependency injection for ease of testing.  At the lowest level, I have methods like “retrieveUserInfo” that accepts a connection interface and a query object.

When Unit testing, I *could* actually create a connection to the telephony system, get back a given user, and check it for the correct data.  This test is meaningful to me as it lets me know both my Middleware and the underlying OEM libraries are working correctly; however, because it’s actually creating a connection to an outside system, it seems more like an integration test to me (the test will fail if you can’t connect to the telephony system, a user is not configured as expected, I have some bug in my business logic, or there is an issue with the underlying libraries).

Should this test be labeled as an integration test?  If so, how would I go about attempting to *unit* test methods like “retrieveUserInfo”?  How do I properly segment these 2 types of tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining what a 'unit' is, is quite difficult. But if what you're testing is putting calls on external libraries that actually call to different systems, then you're definitely in the realm of integration testing.

What a unit is limited to is a bit subjective, but might be restricted to a class or public method on a class.

If you want to unit test a method that calls methods on an external dependency, then that's something you want to mock or stub (see [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) for a good mocking library).

Comment: So I could have one Visual Studio project dedicated to*unit* testing where I mock external dependencies and test my business logic and another VS project dedicated to integration testing where I actually make calls out to the external libraries... sound about right?

Comment: you would certainly have a separate unit test project, but mocking is not set in stone; one solution could be extracting an interface for your telephony system (ITelephony), adding a fake implementation (MockTelephony), wiring that up - all done in code; in your unit test project you'll just switch to using the mock (which can return some predefined data)

Comment: Yeah, it's common to split up your integration and unit tests that way. Some people might want you to shy away from integration tests period. All test suites inevitably lead to overhead test maintenance, integration tests more so than unit tests.